# change look in sharepoint 2013 programatically

Tags: 2013, theme

I want to change the look of the sharepoint 2013 site programatically, I have tried setting up different theme but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First you need to understand themes in 2013.

Start [here](http://sharepointroot.com/2012/07/18/sharepoint-2013-themes/) for the basics

Then [here](http://www.sharepointblog.co.uk/2012/10/creating-sharepoint-2013-themes-first-look-gotchas-provisioning-with-visual-studio-2012/) to grasp how to make a custom one

Then you need to understand where and how they are set from this, then you can alter it., something like this:

```
ThmxTheme oTheme = ThmxTheme.Open(siteCollection,"_catalogs/theme/themename.thmx");
oTheme.ApplyTo(oWeb, false);
oWeb.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of achieving this. It can be done by creating custom masterpages, custom CSS files etc. etc. etc.

It all depends on which part of the SharePoint 2013 you want to change.